# VB .net filter datagridview where datasource are stored procedure dsql pivot

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

Can someone help me with this code?
I've a stored procedure that returns a list of objects joined calendar:

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cale AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ini AS DATETIME
DECLARE @fin AS DATETIME

SET @ini = (SELECT MIN(VerAvv) FROM CalendariVer)
SET @fin = (SELECT MAX(VerSca) FROM CalendariVer)


SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), Data, 103))
                FROM Calendario WHERE Data BETWEEN CAST(@ini AS DATE)
                AND CAST(@fin AS DATE)
                GROUP BY Data
                ORDER BY Data
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


SET @cale = 'SELECT CalId, PiaId, PiaAcr, VerId, VerCod, Ver, Avvio, Chiusura, '+@cols+'
FROM            (SELECT dbo.CalendariVer.CalId, dbo.CalendariVer.PiaId, dbo.CalendariVer.PiaAcr, dbo.CalendariVer.VerId, dbo.CalendariVer.VerCod, dbo.CalendariVer.Ver, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), dbo.CalendariVer.VerAvv, 103) AS Avvio, 
                 CONVERT(nvarchar(10), dbo.CalendariVer.VerSca, 103) AS Chiusura, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), dbo.CalendariVer.LezDal, 108) + '' - '' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), dbo.CalendariVer.LezAl, 108) AS Orario, 
                 CONVERT(nvarchar(10), dbo.Calendario.Data, 103) AS Data
                 FROM dbo.CalendariVer RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Calendario ON CAST(dbo.CalendariVer.Lez AS date) = dbo.Calendario.Data
         WHERE CalID IS NOT NULL                                                    
                 GROUP BY dbo.CalendariVer.CalId, dbo.CalendariVer.PiaId, dbo.CalendariVer.PiaAcr, dbo.CalendariVer.VerId, dbo.CalendariVer.VerCod, dbo.CalendariVer.Ver, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), dbo.CalendariVer.VerAvv, 103), 
                 CONVERT(nvarchar(10), dbo.CalendariVer.VerSca, 103), CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), dbo.CalendariVer.LezDal, 108) + '' - '' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), dbo.CalendariVer.LezAl, 108), CONVERT(nvarchar(10), 
                 dbo.Calendario.Data, 103)) AS c
            PIVOT (MAX(Orario) FOR Data IN ('+@cols+')) AS p'

EXEC (@cale)
```

All work. I've a function in vb that recall:

```vb
Public Function Calendario_Ver() As DataTable
    Dim cale As New DataTable()

    Try
        Acon()
        Dim cal As New SqlCommand("CalendarioVer", con)
        cal.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim trova As New SqlDataAdapter(cal)
        trova.Fill(cale)
        Ccon()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Interaction.MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try

    Return cale
End Function
```

And fill a DataGridView with this code:

```vb
Private Sub CaricaCalendario()
    Try
        With CalVerDataGridView
            .Refresh()
            .DataSource = Calendario_Ver()
            .Columns(0).Visible = False
            .Columns(1).Visible = False
            .Columns(3).Visible = False
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Piano"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Progetto"
            .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Versione"
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        Interaction.MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

All work too, but how I can filter datasource or datagridview by columns `piano`,`versione` and `ver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a `DataTable`, how the data got there is irrelevant.  Bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid.  To filter the data, set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

If you really want to do it without the `BindingSource`, bind the table directly to the grid and set the `DefaultView.RowFilter` of the `DataTable`.

For example:

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource

myBindingSource.Filter = $"SomeColumn LIKE '%{myTextBox.Text}%'"
```

Comment: I tried `BindingSource`, but nothing change into `DataGridView`.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: I entered this code in a sub:

`Public Sub SelezionePiani()

            Dim pia As New BindingSource

            pia.DataSource = Calendario_Ver()


            With CalVerDataGridView

                .Refresh()

                .DataSource = pia.Filter("PiaId = '" & CalVerPiaComboBox.SelectedValue & "'")

                          End With

    End Sub`

Comment: It's hard to read that code in a comment but it doesn't look right to me.  Check out the example in my answer. You set the `DataSource` properties once, when you retrieve the data. You then set the `Filter` wen ever you need to change what the user sees. If the filter value is coming from a `ComboBox` then that would likely be on the `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectionChangeCommitted` event.

Comment: It does work if it's done properly. You're obviously not doing it properly. Ideally you should edit your question and show the code you're currently using so that we can see what's wrong with it but I'm not sure that you can do that until you have a few more posts. It's not rocket surgery though. The `DataSource` is not supposed to change. You set the `DataSource` once when you retrieve the data and then you set the `Filter` when you want to change what's displayed. I've done it before myself many times so I know that it works.